# Haproxy HTTP to HTTPs redirection with multiple backend path

Tags: haproxy

My haproxy server is a.b.c.d & my application is running on somedomain:443 & somedomain:8443 , need redirections like below.

```
http://a.b.c.d  => https://somedomain.com//some/path/here
            => https://somedomain.com:8443//some/path/here


http://a.b.c.d:8080 =>  https://somedomain.com:8080//some/path/here
```

Comment: Please share the steps you have taken to attempt to reach your solution. Right now it appears you have not done anything to solve the problem. Have you looked at https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.8/configuration.html#redirect ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally modified the configuration like below. **Need backend RB0-web roundrobin manner.**

```html
listen FrontEnd  IP:80
        mode http
        log global
        acl is_web path -i /
        acl is_web1 path -i /1
        acl is_web2 path -i /2
        acl is_report path -i /report

        use_backend B1-web if is_web1
        use_backend B2-web if is_web2
        use_backend RB0-web if is_web
        use_backend B-Report if is_report

backend B1-web
        mode http
        redirect code 301 location https://FQDN/web/ws/login/ulogin

backend B2-web
        mode http
        redirect code 301 location https://FQDN:8443/web/ws/login/ulogin

backend RB0-web
        mode http
        balance roundrobin
        option forwardfor
        redirect code 301 location https://FQDN:8443/web/ws/login/ulogin
        redirect code 301 location https://FQDN/web/ws/login/ulogin

backend B-Report
        mode http
        balance roundrobin
        option forwardfor
        redirect code 301 location https://FQDN:8080/jasperserver/login.html
```